# Can't dispose PdfReader without disposing Document and PdfWriter

Tags: c#, itext

To make a PDF composed by the first page of many PDFs I use this code:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(pathPorducedPDFs, "function1.pdf"), FileMode.Create))
using (Document document = new Document(PageSize.A2))
using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs))
{
    document.Open();

    PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

    foreach (string pdfPath in Directory.GetFiles(pathOriginalPDFs).OrderBy(x => x).ToList())
    {
        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath))
        {
            PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
            document.NewPage();
            cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
            document.Add(new Paragraph(pdfPath));
        }
    }

    document.Close();
    writer.Close();
    fs.Close();
}
```

But it looks like, disposing the PdfReader makes the Document and Writer to dispose too.

Infact, the line `document.Close();` throws the Exception:

> System.ObjectDisposedException

Why is this happening?

---

By not disposing the PdfReader you avoid the error, but from my point of view, doing that, is wrong, and this question is to understand WHY this happens!

---

**Solution thanks to @mkl:**

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(pathPorducedPDFs, "function1.pdf"), FileMode.Create))
using (Document document = new Document(PageSize.A2))
using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs))
{
    document.Open();

    PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

    foreach (string pdfPath in Directory.GetFiles(pathOriginalPDFs).OrderBy(x => x).ToList())
    {
        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath))
        {
            PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
            document.NewPage();
            cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
            document.Add(new Paragraph(pdfPath));
            writer.FreeReader(reader);
        }
    }

    document.Close();
    writer.Close();
    fs.Close();
}
```

Comment: What happens if you take out all the `.Close()`'s out as the `using` statements should do your garbage collection for you?

Comment: @John it still throws the System.ObjectDisposedException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
writer.FreeReader(reader);
```

before the closing bracket of the `reader`'s `using` block.

After importing a page from a reader `PdfWriter` keeps track of that reader but does not yet actually copy all data from that page to the target document. It finishes copying and releases its link to that reader only during the `FreeReader` call or when closing.

This allows iText to not unnecessarily duplicate resources when copying page contents from multiple pages of the same source document.

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution!